# Почему не выполняются условия скрипта $(window).resize?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, условия, resize

Есть на сайте товарные секции, в которых хочу выполнить определенные действия при определенных размерах экрана. Не могу понять почему не выполняется условия скрипта `$(window).width()`? 
До этого этапа в консоли прослеживаю, что все выполняется..

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  console.log("resize");
  $('.main-product .product-frame').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var height = $this.find('.product-section h3').height();
    if (height > 21) {
      if (!$this.find('.variations_form').length) {
        console.log("simple");
        if ($(window).width() >= 992 && $(window).width() < 1200) {
          console.log("simple price");
        }
        if ($(window).width() >= 768 && $(window).width() < 991) {
          console.log("simple price");
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="main-product">
  <div class="product-frame">
    <div class="product-section">
      <h3>Товар 1</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-frame">
    <div class="product-section">
      <h3>Товар 2</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробовал ваш код тут: https://jsfiddle.net/yhr6Lh78/ всё работает. Вы уверены, что вы проводили правильные тесты?

Comment: `$(window).trigger('resize');` чтобы СРАЗУ сработало при загрузке страницы

Comment: @xaja а куда его только поместить вот вопрос? вместо, вместе и после функции `$(window).resize();`

Comment: @Vartlok думаю да. может быть, нельзя в данном случае использовать `var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); jQuery(function($){ "use strict"; });` а только `$(document).ready() {}`?

Comment: После функции..

Comment: @xaja не прокатывает.. интересно, что если оставить только одно условие `if ($(window).width() >= 992 && $(window).width() < 1200) {
          console.log("simple price");
        }`, а второе исключить, то все отрабатывает нормально

Comment: вы что-то не то делаете впринципе... такая большая нагрузка на браузер с миллионом просчетов. очень советую посмотреть в сторону css mediaqueries. Или давайте сначала - вы что сделать то хотите?

Comment: @xaja я бы с удовольствием решал это с помощью `css mediaqueries`, но блоки добавляются динамически и поэтому пересчет нужен именно скриптом, т.к. если использовать медиа запросы css, то они применяются раньше, чем в блоках произойдут необходимые изменения - на выходе лажа..

Comment: мне нужно расположить элементы в блоках определенным способом на всех разрешениях в зависимости от высоты картинок в блоке и текста, размеры которых заранее не известны, вычисляются только при подтягивании с базы, т.е. в итоге добиться правильно расположения элементов в универсальном блоке на всех разрешениях экранов - как-то так.. вот я и пытаюсь это сделать с помощью скрипта

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/ чтото такое нужно?

Comment: http://packery.metafizzy.co/ или даже вот так

Comment: @xaja спасибо за интересную библиотеку (насколько понимаю лицензия для ком сайтов платная и она не дружит с `jquery`?), но мне она не подойдет, ибо элементы нужно расположить внутри блока, а не сами блоки между собой